# Find top-level parent in List with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of user-defined objects that have an ID and a ParentID. The list looks something like this.

```
ParentID     ID
  123        345
  123        456
  456        567
  456        678
  678        789
```

I need a LINQ statement to find the top level parent; that is, all of the objects where the ParentID does not exist in as an ID (in this example, only 123).

Here is what I have so far and it is returning 567,678,789.

```
parentList = baseList.Where(b => !baseList.Select(o => o.ParentID).Distinct().Contains(b.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: If nobody answers this I'll hit it when not in mobile. You'll want to join the list with a not condition against itself. What you have now is super inefficient, it'll rebuild the ids enum for every iteration. Full syntax later on if no one picks up on this comment :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current query is trying to find all the items where their ID doesn't correspond to any other item's parent ID--in other words, you're finding all childless nodes.

What it sounds like you want is all the parentless nodes--those whose parent ID doesn't match any other item's ID.

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(baseList.Select(o => o.ID));
var itemsWithNoParent = baseList.Where(o => !ids.Contains(o.ParentID))
    .ToList();
```

I'm using a `HashSet<>` to ensure reasonable `.Contains()` performance on large collections.

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
parentList = baseList
  .where(parent => !baseList.Any(possibleParent => possibleParent.ID == parent.ParentID))
  .ToList();
```

I use this a lot on small (less than 100,000) collections.

I might as well add this too; how to easily create a tree view from this:

```
public class Node
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
  public Node ParentNode { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Node> nodes = .....

nodeTree = nodes.Select(n =>
{
  n.Nodes = nodes.Where(n2 => n2.ParentId == n.Id).ToList();
  n.ParentNode = nodes.FirstOrDefault(n2 => n2.Id == n.ParentId)
  return n;
})
.Where(n => n.ParentNode == null)
.ToList();
```

Comment: I like the single statement

Comment: I updated it to actually create a tree structure and return only parents.